Trying to embed various types of files in browser using HTML object tag like pdf, images, txt, word & excel files. Not working for word and excel file
`I have used below code to embed files in html :
<object data="../assets/BoardingPass_indigo.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <div>No PDF viewer available</div>
</object>

For pdf, type is 'application/pdf'
images like jpg type is 'image/jpg'
text files - type is 'text/plain'
All of the above files open up in browser nicely, but below files like
.xlsx, .xls, .doc, .docx don't open, either I'm giving the incorrect type or what is the issue I don't understand.
I have tried following types for excel and word files:

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet docx
application/msword - doc
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet -
xlsx

Nothing is working.
`

Can you provide info as you why you would think word or excel files would embed?
